# Issue while appending item in list in a list in python

Tags: python

I think similar questions exist but I can't seem to find them out

```
x=list(([],)*3)
x[0].append(1)
x[1].append(2)
x[2].append(3)
print(x)
```

I want the result to look like this:

```
[[1],[2],[3]]
```

But instead, I get:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
```

Also I really don't want to use any loops but if it is necessary then I'll try

Comment: Does this answer your question? [List of lists changes reflected across sublists unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly)

Answer (score 2):

Just realized you don't want to use a for loop.

Option 1: no for loops:

```
x = []
x.append([1])
x.append([2])
x.append([3])
print(x)
> [[1], [2], [3]]
```

Option 2: using loops.

Easiest and cleanest way is to use **list comprehension** like this:

```
x = [[i] for i in range(1,4)]
print(x)
> [[1], [2], [3]]
```

Or you can use a plain for loop and create an empty list before:

```
result = []
for i in range(1,4):
    result.append([i])
result
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the first line, use

```py
x = [[] for _ in range(3)]
```

In the current code, `x` is a list of the empty lists which are actually *the same object*. That's how `[...] * n` works; it repeats the same objects `n` times. So appending an item to one of these empty lists would append the item to the others, because they are the same.

Comment: Thanks !! Didn't thought about list comprehension

Answer (score 0):

You can create an empty list first and starts appending each element as a list.

```
x=[]
x.append([1])
x.append([2])
x.append([3])
print(x)
```